# Nest 1.0 does not expose failure reason for failed shards

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

For ES query fired at an index having say 5 shards, if correct results are returned from 4 shards and an exception thrown from one shard, the ES JSON response for _shards section may look something like below:

```
"_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 4,
      "failed": 1,
      "failures": [
         {
            "index": "<indexname>",
            "shard": 4,
            "status": 500,
            "reason": "<error message>"
         }
      ]
   }
```

`ISearchResponse<T>` does expose how many shards succeeded and how many failed but I could not find if it exposes the failure reason. `<error message>` may be something like `IndexOutOfBoundsException[Index: 1, Size: 1]`.

Does anyone out there know how this error message can be obtained using Nest1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed an issue for this and the Nest guys have added this feature with [this fix.](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/commit/b64c61b671b123020410354ea6fcdc418b10bfa7)